# How to combine different data in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables I join them but I got the wrong query data. when I input the amount in the different account name and account number displayed same amount in **latestBalance**, **totalDeposit**, **totalWithdraw**, **totalFess**. I wonder separate amounts it depends on the account name or account number.

```
    SELECT c.company_name, p.provider_name, a.account_name, a.account_number, a.balance, a.date_added, SUM(a.balance) +
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(dop.amount), 0) FROM deposit dop WHERE dop.provider = p.id ) -
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(wd.amount_withdraw), 0) FROM withdraw wd WHERE wd.provider = p.id ) -
    (SELECT IFNULL(sum(wd.fees), 0) FROM withdraw wd  WHERE wd.provider = p.id )AS latestBalance ,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(dp.amount), 0 )FROM deposit dp WHERE dp.provider = p.id ) AS totalDeposit,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(wed.amount_withdraw), 0) FROM withdraw AS wed WHERE wed.provider = p.id ) AS totalWithdraw,
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(wed.fees), 0) FROM withdraw AS wed WHERE wed.provider = p.id ) AS totalFees
    FROM accounts a
    INNER JOIN provider p ON p.id = a.provider
    INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = a.company
    GROUP BY a.id
```

[image]

Comment: A lot of the links to the sub tables (i.e. withdraw), you only use the provider.  As there seems to be multiple accounts under each provider - I would have expected some link to this as well.

Comment: @NigelRen what kind of link you mean ?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the tables, it will help to understand how the are related.